# Android Upload File to server giving a 'Source File Does not exist' error

Tags: android, android-file

I am coding an activity to upload any types of files to a server.

It retrieves the file name just fine and assigns it to a TextView; but, when I select my upload button it quickly gives me a "Source File Does not exist' error and does not upload the file to my server. (The PHP code is working fine, as I have used it in other places)

I believe the issue is with the uploadFilePath variable in the OnActivityResult. I'm not sure why. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Upload call:

```js
private void uploadFile(final String media_id) {
        class UploadFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            ProgressDialog uploading;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                uploading = ProgressDialog.show(FileUpload.this, "Uploading File", "Please wait...", false, false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                uploading.dismiss();
                finish();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File uploaded successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String filepath = uploadFilePath;
                String msg = uploadFile(filepath, media_id);
                return msg;
            }
        }
        UploadFile uv = new UploadFile();
        uv.execute();
    }
```

Upload Code:

```js
public String uploadFile(String file, final String id) {

        String fileName = file;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

        File sourceFile = new File(file);
        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
            Log.e("Error", "Source File Does not exist");
            return null;
        }

        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(UPLOAD_URL);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("myFile", fileName);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            //Adding Parameter name

            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"media_id\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(media_id); // mobile_no is String variable
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            //Adding Parameter filepath

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            String filepath="url"+fileName;

            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filepath\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(filepath); // mobile_no is String vaiable
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            //Adding Media File Parameter
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"myFile\";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            Log.i("Result", "Initial .available : " + bytesAvailable);
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                rd.close();
            } catch (IOException ioex) {
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }else {
            return "Could not upload";
        }
    }
```

OnActivityResult code:

```js
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_DOC) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Get the Image from data
                Uri selectedFilePath = data.getData();

                String uriString = selectedFilePath.toString();
                File fileToUpload = new File(uriString);
                uploadFilePath = fileToUpload.getAbsolutePath();

                if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
                    Cursor cursor = null;
                    try {
                        cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedFilePath, null, null, null, null);
                        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            uploadFileName =         cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            filename.setText(uploadFileName);
                            uploadFile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            mEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            mSplashImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    } finally {
                        cursor.close();
                    }
                } else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
                    uploadFileName = fileToUpload.getName();
                    filename.setText(uploadFileName);
                    uploadFile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mSplashImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }else {
                    filename.setText("Invalid file type");
                }
            }else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                Toast.makeText(this, "User Canceled File Request.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "File Request failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error loading File. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

UPLOAD_URL:

```html
if (isset($_POST['media_id']) && isset($_POST['file'])) {
 // receiving the post params
 $media_id = $_POST['media_id'];
 $filepath = $_POST['file'];
 
 if ($filepath != null){
 
 $file_path = "uploads/$media_id.pdf";
 $file = $_FILES['myFile']['name'];
 $file_tmp = $_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'];
 $user = $db->storeFile($filepath, $media_id);
 
 move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_path);
 
 $user = $db->storeFile($filepath, $media_id);
 
 if ($user) {
    // user stored successfully
           $response["error"] = FALSE;
           $response["file"]["media_id"] = $user["media_id"];
           echo json_encode($response);
       } else {
            // user failed to store
           $response["error"] = TRUE;
           $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in upload!";
           echo json_encode($response);
        }
 }
} else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Error uploading file.";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

storeFile function:

```html
  public function storeFile($file, $media_id) {
 
 $filename = "***.com/uploads/$media_id.pdf";
 
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE files SET file=? WHERE media_id=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $filename, $media_id);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
 
    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT media_id FROM files WHERE media_id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $media_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();
 
        return $user;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `RL url = new URL(UPLOAD_URL)` what is the value for `UPLOAD_URL`?

Comment: `a "Source File Does not exist' error `. Well dat is your own error string and not informative. Moreover wrong. `if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
            Log.e("Error", "Source File Does not exist"`. Well it is not a file you should log. To check if a file exists use `file.exist`..

Comment: `believe the issue is with the uploadFilePath variable `. Could well be. So tell us how it looks like. You should of course check if the file exists before you call the upload function.

Comment: And your problem has nothing to do with uploading. You just cant check if a file exists. Thats all.

Comment: Tsangares - UPLOAD_URL added to the initial post. Greenapps - I added in your suggestion, the code now is:  `if (!sourceFile.exists())`, it returns the same error message that I set. Which I assume means that the file isn't being passed to the Upload section of the code. Does this part: `uploadFilePath = fileToUpload.getAbsolutePath();` not assign the correct file path for the value being passed to the upload?